# How can I get RGB pixels from an opengl FrameBufferObject for libx264 encoding?

Tags: opengl, rgb, pixel, fbo, libx264

I want to get RGB pixels from the FrameBufferObject: fboName.
Is there any method ?
Do memmory map from GPU to CPU cost large time ?

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboName);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboName);     
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `glReadPixels` to read the image from the framebuffer. You can either pack directly to client memory, or you may use a intermediary Pixel Buffer Object to allow for asynchronous operation and memory mapping.

> Do memory map from GPU to CPU cost large time?

You've to copy the data from GPU memory to system memory anyway. If it's done through a memory map (i.e. triggering DMA transfer by page fault) or explicitly by glGetBufferSubData (using a PBO) or glReadPixels makes no big difference regarding bandwidth utilization and performance. Most important is, that the pixel format requested matches the format of the data on the GPU side, otherwise a costly conversion has to be performed.

Since you want to feed the data to `libx264` I'd say using a mapped buffer would work the best, so that you can interleave libx264 processing of the previous frame with asynchronous transfer of the next frame.